# Page Object Pattern and driver.findElements without any element found

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

From wiki document https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory I found that, if script found some ement using eg.
`@FindBy(id = "q") WebElement q;`

the sentence:

```
 q.sendKeys(text);
```

is equivalent to:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("q")).sendKeys(text);
```

but how can I using Annotation in POM for:

```
driver.findElements(By.id("q")).isEmpty() ?
```

Currently I just use pure Selenium winthout Annotation, eg.

```
 if(!driver.findElements(By.id("q")).isEmpty()) {
    q.click }
```

Of course, I can use try/cath, but in POM there should be something Annotation for 'findElement**s**'.

Comment: Just check your element for null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you ask for is not a `Selenium WebDriver` thing. It's Java.

`isEmpty()` method belongs to `List` interface. `List` is returned after invoking `findElements()` method.

If you want to use `@FindBy` and check whether `List` is empty then do the following:

```
@FindBy(id = "q")
WebElement element;

@FindBy(id = "q")
List<WebElement> listOfElements;

public void someMethod() {
    //can't use `isEmpty()` on `element` because it's NOT a list
    listOfElements.isEmpty(); //that's how you can use it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the [*The PageFactory Documentation*](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) to use the *PageFactory*, you need to declare some fields on a *PageObject* that are either *WebElement* or *List*, for example :

- **`WebElement`** :

  ```
  @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "foobar") WebElement foobar;
  ```
- **`List<WebElement>`** :

  ```
  @FindBy(how = How.TAG_NAME, using = "a") List<WebElement> links;
  ```

So the *PageFactory* design is based on the principple that we have to declare the variable and the PageFactory will search for an element on the page that matches the field name of the WebElement in the class. It does this by first looking for an element with a matching *Locator Strategy*.

So, to implement the **@FindBy** Annotation in POM as per `driver.findElements(By.id("q")).isEmpty()` you can use the following code block :

```
@FindBy(how = How.TAG_NAME, using = "a") List<WebElement> links;

public void myFunction() 
{
    if(!links.isEmpty()) 
    {
        for(WebElement ele:links)
            ele.click();
    }
}
```